# roboearth detection_result listener

Tags: ros, object-detection, roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to write a Python program to listen the detection_results topic that is published by re_kinect_object_detector based on this [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29). However, the datatype of the topics that I am subscribing to and the ones published do not seem to match up. I have tried different types after going through re_msgs and the auto-generated _DetectionResult.py in re_kinect_object_detector but nothing seems to work. Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('kinect_object_tracker')
import rospy
import re_kinect_object_detector

def callback(data):
    print "Got something"
    #rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_name() + "I heard %s", data.data)

def listener():
    rospy.init_node('getObjectPose')
    rospy.Subscriber("re_kinect/detection_results", re_kinect_object_detector.DetectionResult, callback)
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener()
```

When I run this node, I get an error saying that DetectionResult is not a module in re_kinect_object_detector. I tried using DetectedObject from re_msgs but then re_kinect_object_detector gave me a red colored error saying:

```
[ERROR] [1322431132.952748877]: Client [/getObjectPose] wants topic /re_kinect/detection_results to have datatype/md5sum [re_msgs/DetectedObject/fbf421ad7ea115e18f287b539c57644a], but our version has [re_kinect_object_detector/DetectionResult/49fd3ba0170db3e28d61de95d1d6d5c8]. Dropping connection.
```

My question is, what is the type that I need to pass in the Subscriber call for getting the detection_results.

Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12109/roboearth-detection_result-listener/) by [Sudarshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/291/sudarshan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2011-11-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Message definitions are found under a "package.msg.X" namespace, so:

```
import re_kinect_object_detector.msg

...

rospy.Subscriber("re_kinect/detection_results", re_kinect_object_detector.msg.DetectionResult, callback)
```

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0